# How can I fix my Navigation/Frame Error in WPF? Error #CS1061

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation, frame

I am trying to set up a navigation page with a frame inside and I have gotten this error I can't seem to get rid of. My frame has stopped working and displaying the pages I have connected to them.

I have tried looking up this error `CS1061` and tried seeing where the error is. It seems to be conflicting with `Navigated="Frame_Navigated` in MainWindow.xaml. Perhaps anyone can point me out what exactly is wrong? It worked before.

MainWindow.xaml.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TataSteel_Gamification_01
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Display Items in Frame
            Loaded += Window_Loaded;

        }

        Boolean MenuToggle = true;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Open the Start Frame
            frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
        }

        private void Btn_Page1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Open Page 1
            frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml Code (Cut out uneccessary parts):

```
<Window x:Name="ApplicationFrame" x:Class="TataSteel_Gamification_01.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TataSteel_Gamification_01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1200" Width="1920" Background="#FF1C2431">

<Grid x:Name="Grid_Display" ShowGridLines="False">

<Viewbox x:Name="Viewbox_Frame" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

<Frame x:Name="frame" Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Navigated="Frame_Navigated" Height="1170" Width="1435"/>

</Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

I expect that the after result will be that the navigation works again so I can display pages within the frame without any errors.

Comment: Have you added Frame_Navigated event in the .cs?

Comment: @JustinCI Now that you mention it, I don't have any Frame_Navigated event in my .cs file. When I try to "Open Code" on my frame it also doesn't redirect me to anything. Would you perhaps know how I can add this event properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Navigated="Frame_Navigated"
```

Frame_Navigated is function called when your frame is actually navigated. You doesn't seem to have anyhow implemented it in your **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

Here is what you are missing in .cs file:

```
private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
 // your code to handle navigated frame
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that indeed, when I try to "Open Code" on the frame it also doesn't redirect me to anything in the .cs file. Would you perhaps know how I can implement this properly?

Comment: @Stabilis Just put this code in your .cs file and your project will run properly.

Comment: Apologies, I did not notice you added code, I might of responded too quickly. It's working again, thank you very much for your fast responses and help!